# Android Linkify for UK addresses

Tags: android, street-address, linkify

Regarding the use of Linkify on a textbox / label does anyone know how to enable a UK address to work?

Using a US or Canadian address works fine, but changing to an international address does not get the same link-to-map treatment.

I would like to avoid building a pattern matching library to compensate for this.

Any help or pointers to documentation related to this issue?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Even Canadian addresses doesn't seem to work for me.